# VBA code to copy a selection just as cut does, so that paste doesn't modify references?

Tags: excel, vba

When I copy and paste, then excel moves the cell references down. E.g. References to cell B2 on line 3 become references to line B3 on line 4.

With cut and paste, this doesn't happen, and references to cell B2 remain references to B2.

I want the behavior of the cut and paste, but without losing the original content.

I've tried Recording a Macro, then pressing F2, SHIFT-HOME, copy and escape, and excel records absolutely nothing. But this is what I want the macro to do, so that when I copy it, it copies it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Put the following in a standard module:

```
Dim sForm As String

Sub ccopy()
    sForm = ActiveCell.Formula
End Sub

Sub ppaste()
    ActiveCell.Formula = sForm
End Sub
```

Then assign the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> to **ccopy** and the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>  to **ppaste**

This should simulate Copy/Paste, but leave cell references intact.

This can be modified for multiple cells.

**EDIT#1:**

This new **ppaste** will handle the case of:

*single cell -> multiple cells*

```
Sub ppaste()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Formula = sForm
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! How would you modify it for multiple cells? Is there an ActiveRange or something similar?

Comment: See my **EDIT#1.**  to perform *multiple cells -> multiple cells* would be a significant change.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work, here's what I came up with:

```
Dim formulas() As String
Dim initCopyCol As Integer
Dim initCopyRow As Integer
Dim columns As Integer
Dim rows As Integer

Sub copyFormulaRange()

    initCopyCol = Selection.Column
    initCopyRow = Selection.row

    columns = Selection.columns.Count
    rows = Selection.rows.Count

    ReDim formulas(1 To columns, 1 To rows)

    For i = 1 To columns
        For j = 1 To rows
            formulas(i, j) = Cells(initCopyRow + j - 1, initCopyCol + i - 1).Formula
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

Sub pasteFormulaRange()

    Dim initPasteCol As Integer
    Dim initPasteRow As Integer

    initPasteCol = Selection.Column
    initPasteRow = Selection.row

    For i = 1 To columns
        For j = 1 To rows
            Cells(initPasteRow + j - 1, initPasteCol + i - 1).Formula = formulas(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```